# Register a "Hello World" DBus service, object and method using Python

Tags: python, dbus

I'm trying to export a DBus service named `com.example.HelloWorld`, with an object `/com/example/HelloWorld`, and method `com.example.HelloWorld.SayHello`  that prints "hello, world" if the method is called using

```
dbus-send --system --type=method_call --dest=com.example.HelloWorld /com/example/HelloWorld com.example.HelloWorld.SayHello
```

So my question is how do you make a simple DBus service with a single method that prints "hello, world" (on its own stdout).

Comment: When I added DBus support to my favorite terminal emulator, this was my first attempt: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~cmsj/terminator/dbus/revision/1079/terminatorlib/ipc.py -- sorry but years have passed and I can't remember much about DBus

Comment: Forgot the link to an important bit: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~cmsj/terminator/dbus/revision/1079/terminator

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When using `dbus-python` the following setup for exporting a D-Bus service works:

```
import gobject
import dbus
import dbus.service

from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop
DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)


OPATH = "/com/example/HelloWorld"
IFACE = "com.example.HelloWorld"
BUS_NAME = "com.example.HelloWorld"


class Example(dbus.service.Object):
    def __init__(self):
        bus = dbus.SessionBus()
        bus.request_name(BUS_NAME)
        bus_name = dbus.service.BusName(BUS_NAME, bus=bus)
        dbus.service.Object.__init__(self, bus_name, OPATH)

    @dbus.service.method(dbus_interface=IFACE + ".SayHello",
                         in_signature="", out_signature="")
    def SayHello(self):
        print "hello, world"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = Example()
    loop = gobject.MainLoop()
    loop.run()
```

The example is modified from your code with how the mainloop is setup for `dbus-python` with the following lines:

```
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop
DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
```

The mainloop is started after the service has been initialized in the last section of the example:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = Example()
    loop = gobject.MainLoop()
    loop.run()
```

The full example above can be called by calling `dbus-send` like so:

```
dbus-send --session --print-reply --type=method_call --dest=com.example.HelloWorld /com/example/HelloWorld com.example.HelloWorld.SayHello.SayHello
```

Note that this line is also modified from your question by specifying `--session` and not `--system`, and that the way to specify what method to call is to append the method name to the end of the interface and thus we have the double `SayHello` part there. If that was not intended, you can remove the added `SayHello` from the interface when exporting your method in the service like this:

```
# only 'IFACE' is used here
@dbus.service.method(dbus_interface=IFACE,
                     in_signature="", out_signature="")
```

And then the service can be called like so:

```
dbus-send --session --print-reply --type=method_call --dest=com.example.HelloWorld /com/example/HelloWorld com.example.HelloWorld.SayHello
```

Also see e.g. [How to use the existing services in DBus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34148109/how-to-use-the-existing-services-in-dbus/34197133#34197133) for more examples of minimal service and client code, and [Role of Mainloops, Event Loops in DBus service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33428804/role-of-mainloops-event-loops-in-dbus-service/33432541#33432541) for some info about the mainloop stuff.

Comment: On call `com.example.HelloWorld.SayHello.SayHello` looks funny, as Say Hello is there twice. If your service has only single interface, simplifying decorator into `@dbus.service.method(dbus_interface=IFACE, in_signature=None, out_signature=None)` allows using single Say Hello.