# Invoking a class method from a Linux process which is a python script

Tags: python, linux, class, methods, process

The Linux machine is running a process like given below:

```
root     18983 18961  0 02:22 pts/0    00:00:04 /xxx/grpcEnv/bin/python /xxx/python/exabgp_shim/ExaBGP_server.py
```

The python script `ExaBGP_server.py` basically starts a server and is waiting in an infinite while loop. The script also has some classes with different methods defined.

Question:

How to invoke a class method of the above python script when the process is already running ?

Comment: Ask the script to execute it for you.

Comment: @sashoalm: I am sorry, but the comment seems too critical.

Comment: OK, sorry about that. Could you kindly provide the actual code of ExaBGP_server.py? Also, could you provide an example of how you intend to "invoke a method"? Invoke it **from where**?

Answer (score 2):

There's no easy way to do that unless you have code in the server to also give you access to an interpreter while it's running, or on launching it.

EDIT: [This "manhole" library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/manhole) looks promising for your use case, though like the other ideas listed it does require some modification of the server code to implement.

Is this code you wrote?  If so, you could modify it to run the server in a background thread, and then use the `code` module to launch an interactive interpreter on the console with the appropriate modules/class instances (if needed) accessible.  This only works for debugging, since this effectively turns your noninteractive server into an interactive Python process that happens to run a server in the background.

The Twisted library supported a telnet or SSH-based [manhole](http://www.lothar.com/tech/twisted/manhole.xhtml) feature, where you could essentially shell into the running Python process at any time, but integrating Twisted into a non-Twisted code base is not worth the trouble for this feature.  I think there've been other implementations of this concept, including some that provide fancy HTML/JS interfaces, but I don't have the names/links handy.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly the problem that DBus solves. It allows you to invoke methods from another process.

I had asked a question about creating Hello World server using DBus, [Register a "Hello World" DBus service, object and method using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482691/register-a-hello-world-dbus-service-object-and-method-using-python).

This is how the code for the server looks:

```
import gobject
import dbus
import dbus.service

from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop
DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)


OPATH = "/com/example/HelloWorld"
IFACE = "com.example.HelloWorld"
BUS_NAME = "com.example.HelloWorld"


class Example(dbus.service.Object):
    def __init__(self):
        bus = dbus.SessionBus()
        bus.request_name(BUS_NAME)
        bus_name = dbus.service.BusName(BUS_NAME, bus=bus)
        dbus.service.Object.__init__(self, bus_name, OPATH)

    @dbus.service.method(dbus_interface=IFACE + ".SayHello",
                         in_signature="", out_signature="")
    def SayHello(self):
        print "hello, world"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = Example()
    loop = gobject.MainLoop()
    loop.run()
```

And you can use `dbus-send` to call it.